# How do you tile over a porch stepping slab that has a nose?

Tags: stairs, tiling, porch

In the picture below everything is cross section:
1 -door
2 -porch slab concrete
3 -stepping stone that has a nose

I would like to tile the porch and the stepping stone but I am not sure how to tile that nose
Should I build up cement on the vertical side of that slab under the nose to make the nose disappear like in the second picture ?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How much is the the nose sticking out?  Imagine it is not more than an inch, which is thin for concrete.  Might be better to clean the step well and glue a piece of wood under the nose.

Comment: the wood might rot there if water gets in there. Besides that there is a small gap there between the step and the porch which is currently filled up with polyurethane based filler so if that fails moisture can get in from there as well

Comment: How long is the step?

Comment: it is around 5ft

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were me, I'd cut that nosing off using a concrete blade in an appropriate saw.

You'd end up with the same net effect - no nose and a square tile corner, without worries about water getting behind anything or filler material degrading over time.

Comment: yes I was thikning about that too but it will probably create lots of dust. I am more inclined to do this than to add cement which will come off.

Comment: Dust is a short-term, one time thing that can be taken care of by cutting from upwind on a breezy day. ;) One could, I suppose, use a shop vac, instead. A failure of whatever filler is behind there would likely go unnoticed for a long time until the tile on the risers break/fall off because whatever was holding them up has finally given way.

Comment: I have a 4 1/2" angle grinder with stone blade and I have circular saw with stone blade, also the vacuum so I could probably do it.  I am wondering if this thing has metal reinforcement built in (like rebar mesh or similar)

Comment: I wouldn't think there would be any in the nosing, but I'm not a concrete guy, so I can't make any guarantees...

Answer (score 1):

Mix up some Thinset a little dryer than you normally would for laying tile and fill that area in with it. Have a flat board ready to shove up against the edge to prevent the Thinset from settling downward. In instances where I've added mortar to areas like this, I've drilled and screwed in a few Tapcons to about half the width of the nose to help support the mix.... like little rebars.